# How to retrieve customer id from create customer method in Square using Python

Tags: python, square

I'm creating a customer in square and getting the results as follows. What I need is to get the id of customer.

My code :

```
from square.client import Client

client = Client(
    access_token=settings.SQUARE_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    environment=settings.SQUARE_ENVIRONMENT,
)
api_customers = client.customers
request_body = {'idempotency_key': idempotency_key, 'given_name': name, 'company_name': company,'phone_number':phone}
result = api_customers.create_customer(request_body)
```

And this is the output:

```
<ApiResponse [{"customer": 
                {"id": "F8M9KDHWPMYGK2108RMQVQ6FHC",
                 "created_at": "2020-10-22T09:14:50.159Z",
                 "updated_at": "2020-10-22T09:14:50Z",
                 "given_name": "mkv5",
                 "phone_number": "900000066666",
                 "company_name": "codesvera",
                 "preferences": {"email_unsubscribed": false},
                 "creation_source": "THIRD_PARTY"}
               }
              ]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using this library ?
https://github.com/square/square-python-sdk/blob/master/square/http/api_response.py

if yes result is an array and APiResponse object.

so first you should do that : `result = result.body`
then to get the ID:  `result['customer']['id']`

Ps : You have exemple in the github doc :
https://github.com/square/square-python-sdk

```
# Initialize the customer count
total_customers = 0
# Initialize the cursor with an empty string since we are 
# calling list_customers for the first time
cursor = ""
# Count the total number of customers using the list_customers method
while True:
    # Call list_customers method to get all customers in this Square account
    result = api_customers.list_customers(cursor)
    if result.is_success():
        # If any customers are returned, the body property 
        # is a list with the name customers.
        # If there are no customers, APIResponse returns
        # an empty dictionary.
        if result.body:
            customers = result.body['customers']
            total_customers += len(customers)
            # Get the cursor if it exists in the result else set it to None
            cursor = result.body.get('cursor', None)
            print(f"cursor: {cursor}")
        else:
            print("No customers.")
            break
    # Call the error method to see if the call failed
    elif result.is_error():
        print(f"Errors: {result.errors}")
        break
    
    # If there is no cursor, we are at the end of the list.
    if cursor == None:
        break

print(f"Total customers: {total_customers}")
```

Comment: I have already tried that .But it shows the error TypeError: 'ApiResponse' object does not support indexing

Comment: then the problem is how you get the result.
What are you using as library ? 
can we see more code like api_customers please